# Can no longer boot Windows 7 after Windows 7/Ubuntu partition cloning to another drive

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7, clone

I recently changed the hard drive of my laptop, from a 500GB HDD to a 256GB SSD.

I did the cloning using GParted for reducing and copying all partitions from HHD to SSD, after which I reinstalled GRUB on the new drive using the tutorial found [here](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/02/how-to-chroot-to-ubuntu-using-live-cd-to-fix-grub-rescue-prompt/)

Ubuntu started without any problems, but Windows refuses to start, with this error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000e

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

`fdisk -l` output :

```
Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048    33,490,943    33,488,896  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery     Environment)
/dev/sda2          33,490,944    33,695,743       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          33,695,744   197,535,743   163,840,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         197,551,305   500,103,449   302,552,145   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         197,554,176   320,929,791   123,375,616  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         320,931,840   337,522,687    16,590,848  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

After investigation, in the process or reinstalled GRUB, I might have messed up a little, and started a first installation of GRUB on the Windows boot partition (sda2) ( before "re"installing it to sda5 )

My Boot Info Summary:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /grub/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img
```

and my complete boot-repair report : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1126849/

Any idea on how to fix the problem ? I started to look at bootsect and bootrec window recovery commands, but I'm afraid of breaking everything just a little more...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have tried `recommended repair` by `boot-repair`? it also fixes windows boot

Comment: yes already have. Didnt change a thing...